# Loop through multidimensional elements in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to loop through HTML to get the content and put into JSON file

I have this this HTML:

```
<div class="main">

  <div class="results">
    <div class="name">joan</div>
    <div class="age">32</div>
  </div>

  <div class="results">
    <div class="name">Sam</div>
    <div class="age">35</div>
  </div>

  <div class="results">
    <div class="name">joo</div>
    <div class="age">32</div>
  </div>

</div>
```

I want the results to look something like this:

```
{
  "1": {
    "name": "joan",
    "age": "32",
  },
  "2": {
    "name": "Sam",
    "age": "35",
  },
  "3": {
      "name": "joo",
      "age": "32",
  },}
```

I tried make it work with this JavaScript structure, but it didn't work:

```
Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("results")).forEach(
  function(element, index, array) {
    var  data = $('.name, .age').text();
    console.log(data);
  });
```

Any idea?

Comment: Thank you so much for your contribution, I really appreciate it. Sorry for not giving you the up vote, I did up vote you now, Regards.

Comment: Sounds great, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are three solutions to achieve the desired result using:

- **jQuery**
- **ECMAScript 6**
- **Plain JavaScript**

And **a proposal to change your data structure to an array**, that will make it easier to use it later.

---

### jQuery solution

You could fill a new object `res` with the desired content

Use the jQuery method [`.each`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) to loop through the `.results` elements:

> **`.each( function )`**
>
> `function`: Function( Integer `index`, Element `element` )
>
> A function to execute for each matched element.

Then get the text content of both `.results`'s child: `.name` and `.age`.

```js
let res = {};

$(".results").each(function(index, element) {

  const [name, age] = [$(this).children('.name').text(), $(this).children('.age').text()];
  
  res[index] = {name, age}

});

console.log(res)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">

  <div class="results">
    <div class="name">joan</div>
    <div class="age">32</div>
  </div>

  <div class="results">
    <div class="name">Sam</div>
    <div class="age">35</div>
  </div>

  <div class="results">
    <div class="name">joo</div>
    <div class="age">32</div>
  </div>

</div>
```

---

### ES6 solution

1. get the array of `.results` elements:

   ```
   [...document.querySelectorAll('.results')]
   ```
2. use the [`.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method to reduce it to an object

   > The `reduce()` method applies a function against an accumulator (here `res`) and each element (here `element`) in the array (here `[...document.querySelectorAll('.results')]`) (from left to right) to reduce it to a single value (here an object).

   1. get the array of children of this current `.result` element with `[...parent.children]`
   2. map this with [`.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to convert this array of elements to an array of their content (with the [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) property):

      ```
      [...parent.children].map(e => e.textContent);
      ```
   3. You can use [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to assign both of these two array elements to the variables `name` and `age`:

      ```
      cons [name, age] = [...parent.children].map(e => e.textContent);
      ```
   4. Add a new property to the `res` object and return `res` for the fololowing element:

      ```
      res[index] = {name, age};

      return res;
      ```

Here is the full code:

```js
const res = [...document.querySelectorAll('.results')].reduce((res, parent, index) => {
  
  const [name, age] = [...parent.children].map(e => e.textContent);
  
  res[index] = {name, age};
  
  return res;
  
}, {});

console.log(res)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">

  <div class="results">
    <div class="name">joan</div>
    <div class="age">32</div>
  </div>

  <div class="results">
    <div class="name">Sam</div>
    <div class="age">35</div>
  </div>

  <div class="results">
    <div class="name">joo</div>
    <div class="age">32</div>
  </div>

</div>
```

---

### Plain JavaScript

- Use [`[].slice.call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) to flatten the [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) instead of the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) (`...`)
- Use a [function expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function) instead of an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

Here is the code:

```js
const res = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.results')).reduce(function(res, parent, index) {
  
  const name = parent.querySelector('.name').textContent;
  const age = parent.querySelector('.age').textContent;
  res[index] = { name, age };
  
  return res;
  
}, {});

console.log(res)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">

  <div class="results">
    <div class="name">joan</div>
    <div class="age">32</div>
  </div>

  <div class="results">
    <div class="name">Sam</div>
    <div class="age">35</div>
  </div>

  <div class="results">
    <div class="name">joo</div>
    <div class="age">32</div>
  </div>

</div>
```

---

### Changing data structure

You might as well use an array to hold the data because you are using integers as keys to the values. In this case, the code will be a little shorter and you can still access the properties by the index: `res[0]`, `res[1]` etc...

```js
const res = [...document.querySelectorAll('.results')].reduce((res, parent) => {
  
  const [name, age] = [...parent.children].map(e => e.textContent);
  
  return res.concat([{name, age}])
  
}, []);

console.log(res)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">

  <div class="results">
    <div class="name">joan</div>
    <div class="age">32</div>
  </div>

  <div class="results">
    <div class="name">Sam</div>
    <div class="age">35</div>
  </div>

  <div class="results">
    <div class="name">joo</div>
    <div class="age">32</div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: that was a great share @Ivan! No doubt it was the best!

Comment: I am glad I could help ;)

Comment: Your third solution works like a charm but when I try to get the image source using `.getAttribute` I get null output values. Any idea?

Comment: @Gad the plain JavaScript one? Where are you using `img` elements? I imagine you have a third child in there, is that right?

Answer (score 1):

With no jQuery, just plain javascript, and very fast, you could do something as simple as this.

Use `index` for the initial object's key, and then create yet another with the `name`/`age` and assign that as its value.

*Note, as newer browsers now support `forEach` on `nodeList`, I went with that, though added a 2nd using `for...loop` for the older one's, which might be even faster :)*

Stack snippet

```js
var data = {};

document.querySelectorAll(".results").forEach(function(el, idx) {
  data[idx+1] = {
                  "name": el.children[0].textContent,
                  "age": el.children[1].textContent
                };
});

console.log(data);
```

```html
<div class="main">

  <div class="results">
    <div class="name">joan</div>
    <div class="age">32</div>
  </div>

  <div class="results">
    <div class="name">Sam</div>
    <div class="age">35</div>
  </div>

  <div class="results">
    <div class="name">joo</div>
    <div class="age">32</div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Stack snippet - using `for...loop`

```js
var data = {}, idx = 0, items = document.querySelectorAll(".results");

for(;idx < items.length; idx++) {
  data[idx+1] = {
                  "name": items[idx].children[0].textContent,
                  "age": items[idx].children[1].textContent
                };
}

console.log(data);
```

```html
<div class="main">

  <div class="results">
    <div class="name">joan</div>
    <div class="age">32</div>
  </div>

  <div class="results">
    <div class="name">Sam</div>
    <div class="age">35</div>
  </div>

  <div class="results">
    <div class="name">joo</div>
    <div class="age">32</div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: If you’re using `Array.from`, you might as well use `map` instead of manually building up the array.

Comment: @Aankhen Just decided to go w/o, as all the latest browser now support `forEach` on `nodeList`

Comment: That’s cool. I learnt something new today! You might want to add a note about compatibility, though.

Comment: @Aankhen Just did...and maybe that _new cool learning_ was good enough for an upvote ;)

Comment: Great! There you go.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution, in pure javascript try this

```js
var data=[]; //declare an obj  container
var objresults= document.getElementsByClassName("results"); //get class element for results
for(let i=0; i < objresults.length; i++) //loop the result elements
{
    data.push(
    {
    [i+1]:{"name":objresults[i].getElementsByClassName("name")[0].innerHTML, 
    "age":objresults[i].getElementsByClassName("age")[0].innerHTML
    }});
   //push the values of its child elements
};

alert(JSON.stringify(data));
console.log(data);
```

```html
<div class="main">

  <div class="results">
    <div class="name">joan</div>
    <div class="age">32</div>
  </div>

  <div class="results">
    <div class="name">Sam</div>
    <div class="age">35</div>
  </div>

  <div class="results">
    <div class="name">joo</div>
    <div class="age">32</div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var array = [];
$('.results').each(function(index, value) {
    array.push({
        "name": value.children[0].innerText,
        "age": value.children[1].innerText
    });
});
// the required result
var finalObject = JSON.stringify(array);
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bcode-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: I have just started answering questions here and I was focussed only on the solution and did not think about the reader's perspective. I'll make sure, I include an explanation in my answers and I appreciate ur feedback